# How to hide specific node from jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am creating a jstree and I want to hide the node having the file extension .pdf I searched too much but I am not getting way to hide that node. what I have tried till now...

jsTree creating

```
$(function () {
   var selectedData;
   $('#jstree').jstree({
      "core": {
         "multiple": true,
         "check_callback": false,
         'themes': {
            "responsive": true,
            'variant': 'larg',
            'stripes': false,
            'dots': false
         }
      },
      "types": {
          "default": {
              "icon": "fa fa-folder icon-state-warning icon-lg"
          },
          "file": {
              "icon": "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
          }
      },
      "plugins": ["dnd", "state", "types", "sort", "checkbox"]
   });           
});

$("#jstree").bind('ready.jstree', function (event, data) {
    var $tree = $(this);
    $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
      flat: true
    }))
   .each(function (index, value) {
       debugger
       var node = $("#jstree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
       var lvl = node.parents.length;
       var idx = index;
       var str = value.text.split('.');
       var count = str.length;

       if (str[count - 1] == "pdf") {

       /* The issue is coming here */
       $("#jstree").jstree(false).hide_node(node);

      }

  });
});
/* This is a different approach I tried */
$('#jstree').on("after_open.jstree", function (e, data) {

   if (data.node.id == 4) {
      var node = $("#jstree").jstree().get_node(this.id);
      node.hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: can you post json/html you may already have data to render tree?.

Comment: <div id="jstree">
        @(Html.TreeView(Model)
                          .EmptyContent("rootrrr")
                          .Children(m => m.Childs)
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "tree" })
                      .ChildrenHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "subItem" })
                          .ItemText(m => m.Name)
                          .ItemTemplate(
                        @<text>
                            <a href="@item.Description" desc="@item.Description">@item.Name</a>
                        </text>)
        )
    </div>

Comment: I am using MVC code based first approach and consuming data in tree via Model   i have dummy data here...
          
            context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Name,
              new Category { ID = 1, Name = "Main Cat1", Pid = null, Description = "Main Cat1" },
              new Category { ID = 2, Name = "Sub Main Cat1", Pid = 1, Description = "Sub Main Cat1" },
              new Category { ID = 3, Name = "Sub Sub.pdf", Pid = 2, Description = "Sub Sub.pdf" },
              new Category { ID = 4, Name = "Main Cat2.pdf", Pid = null, Description }
              );
        
    }

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
$('#jstree').on("ready.jstree", function (e, data) {

    var jsonNodes = $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_json('#', { flat: true });

    $.each(jsonNodes, function (i, val) {

        var treeNode = document.getElementById($(val).attr('id'));
        var nodeText = $(val).attr('text');

        if(nodeText.substr(nodeText.length - 3) == "pdf") {
            $(treeNode).hide();
            //console.log(treeNode + "Found")
        }
    })
})
```

[image of tree before hiding node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYYzd.jpg)

[image of tree after hiding node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMd1w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this ⌚ ✔ ♩ ♪ ♫

```
    function isFiles(){

        // This function shuold be called on mouse enter event on jstree div and jstree change event   ♻

        //get Nodes
        let jsonNodes = $("#folderTree").jstree(true).get_json("#", { flat: true });

        // chk each  node 

            $.each(jsonNodes, function(i, val) {
                if(val.icon=="fa fa-file") <- You can deside ,what you want to chk
                {
                    // OOo  this node is a file soo , removed it
                                
                    let treeNode = document.getElementById($(val).attr("id"));
                    $(treeNode).hide();
                            
                }

        })
    }


    $(document).on("mouseenter click","#folderTree",function(){
    
        isFiles()
    
    })
```